# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to

Tags: java, java-swing, hibernate

tengo el siguiente problema, quiero hacer una consulta a mi db, pra traer una lista  de una clase relacionada, todo trabajado con hibernate, pero cuando quiero imprimir en pantalla me tira el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.historiasclinicas.entidades.Turnos
at com.historiasclinicas.pantallas.PantaListaTurnos.llenarLista(PantaListaTurnos.java:193)
at com.historiasclinicas.pantallas.PantaListaTurnos.access$3(PantaListaTurnos.java:188)
at com.historiasclinicas.pantallas.PantaListaTurnos$2.actionPerformed(PantaListaTurnos.java:127)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

el tema es que no he podido encontrar informacion precisa googleando, debido a que parece ser por varios motivos diferentes.

mi codigo es el siguiente

```
    public static List<Turnos> ConsultarTurno(String especialista, String fecha) {
    SessionFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.err.println("Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    List<Turnos> turnos = new ArrayList<Turnos>();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        Query<Turnos> turno = session.createQuery("select t.fechaTurno, t.estados.estado, t.paciente.id from Turnos as t where t.especialista =:especialista"); 
        turno.setParameter("especialista", especialista);
        turnos = turno.list();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return turnos;
}
```

entidad :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "turnos", catalog = "histocons")
public class Turnos implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8315003380691512767L;
    private Integer id;
    private Estados estados;
    private Paciente paciente;
    private String fechaTurno;
    private String especialista;
    private String horaTurno;

    public Turnos() {
    }

    public Turnos(Estados estados, Paciente paciente, String fechaTurno, String especialista, String horaTurno) {
        this.estados = estados;
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.fechaTurno = fechaTurno;
        this.especialista = especialista;
        this.horaTurno = horaTurno;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "estado", nullable = false)
    public Estados getEstados() {
        return this.estados;
    }

    public void setEstados(Estados estados) {
        this.estados = estados;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "paciente", nullable = false)
    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return this.paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    @Column(name = "fechaTurno", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getFechaTurno() {
        return this.fechaTurno;
    }

    public void setFechaTurno(String fechaTurno) {
        this.fechaTurno = fechaTurno;
    }

    @Column(name = "especialista", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getEspecialista() {
        return this.especialista;
    }

    public void setEspecialista(String especialista) {
        this.especialista = especialista;
    }

    @Column(name = "horaTurno", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getHoraTurno() {
        return this.horaTurno;
    }

    public void setHoraTurno(String horaTurno) {
        this.horaTurno = horaTurno;
    }
}
```

clase pantalla

```
package com.historiasclinicas.pantallas;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.historiasclinicas.ejecucion.Errores;
import com.historiasclinicas.entidades.Turnos;
import com.historiasclinicas.gestores.GestorTurnos;
import com.historiasclinicas.log.Log;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

public class PantaListaTurnos extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4986245537095109601L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private String especialista = PantaLogin.usuario.toString();
private List<Turnos> ListaTurnos = null;
private DateFormat df1;
private JDateChooser dateChooser;
private JButton btnMarcarIngresado;
private JList<Object> List;
private String paciente;
private String fechaTurno;
private Integer Estado;
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public PantaListaTurnos() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/logotipo.png")));
    setTitle("Administrar Turnos Medico");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 890, 444);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnArchivo = new JMenu("Archivo");
    mnArchivo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/iconos/twentytwo/archive.png")));
    menuBar.add(mnArchivo);

    JMenuItem mntmSalir = new JMenuItem("Salir");
    mntmSalir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    mntmSalir.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/iconos/twentytwo/close.png")));
    mnArchivo.add(mntmSalir);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    JLabel lblTurnos = new JLabel("Turnos");
    lblTurnos.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblTurnos.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/iconos/calendar.png")));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTurnos = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblTurnos.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblTurnos.gridwidth = 7;
    gbc_lblTurnos.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblTurnos.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblTurnos.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(lblTurnos, gbc_lblTurnos);

    JLabel lblIcono = new JLabel("");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblIcono = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblIcono.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblIcono.gridwidth = 9;
    gbc_lblIcono.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblIcono.gridx = 14;
    gbc_lblIcono.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(lblIcono, gbc_lblIcono);
    lblIcono.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/logotipo.png")));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.gridheight = 5;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridwidth = 20;
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 1;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    List = new JList<Object>();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(List);

    JButton btnActualizarLista = new JButton("Actualizar Lista");
    btnActualizarLista.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fechaTurno = df1.format(dateChooser.getDate());
            llenarLista();
        }
    });
    btnActualizarLista.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    btnActualizarLista.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/iconos/twentytwo/history.png")));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnActualizarLista = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnActualizarLista.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_btnActualizarLista.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnActualizarLista.gridx = 21;
    gbc_btnActualizarLista.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(btnActualizarLista, gbc_btnActualizarLista);

    JButton btnIngresarATurno = new JButton("Ingresar a Paciente");
    btnIngresarATurno.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    btnIngresarATurno.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/iconos/twentytwo/clipboard.png")));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnIngresarATurno = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnIngresarATurno.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_btnIngresarATurno.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnIngresarATurno.gridx = 21;
    gbc_btnIngresarATurno.gridy = 2;
    contentPane.add(btnIngresarATurno, gbc_btnIngresarATurno);

    btnMarcarIngresado = new JButton("Marcar Ingresado");
    btnMarcarIngresado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                seleccionaTurno();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    Log.crearLog(e1.toString());
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnMarcarIngresado.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    btnMarcarIngresado.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PantaListaTurnos.class.getResource("/imagenes/iconos/twentytwo/check.png")));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnMarcarIngresado = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnMarcarIngresado.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_btnMarcarIngresado.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnMarcarIngresado.gridx = 21;
    gbc_btnMarcarIngresado.gridy = 3;
    contentPane.add(btnMarcarIngresado, gbc_btnMarcarIngresado);

    Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
    dateChooser.setCalendar(c2);
    dateChooser.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_dateChooser = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_dateChooser.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_dateChooser.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_dateChooser.gridx = 21;
    gbc_dateChooser.gridy = 4;
    contentPane.add(dateChooser, gbc_dateChooser);
}

private void llenarLista() {

    ListaTurnos = GestorTurnos.ConsultarTurno(especialista, fechaTurno);
    DefaultListModel<Object> df = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaTurnos.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((Turnos)ListaTurnos.get(i));
        Turnos tu = (Turnos)ListaTurnos.get(i);
        df.addElement(tu.getPaciente()+" "+tu.getEstados());
    }
    List.setModel(df);
}

public void seleccionaTurno() throws IOException {
    try {
        ListaTurnos.get(List.getSelectedIndex()).getPaciente();
            setPaciente(ListaTurnos.get(List.getSelectedIndex()).getPaciente().getApellido());
        ListaTurnos.get(List.getSelectedIndex()).getEstados().getEstado();                  setEstado(ListaTurnos.get(List.getSelectedIndex()).getEstados().getId());
        Turnos turnos = ListaTurnos.get(List.getSelectedIndex());
        Log.crearLog("Cambio de turno fecha "+fechaTurno+",paciente"+paciente);
        if (Estado<3) 
            GestorTurnos.ActualizaEstado(turnos.getPaciente().getDni());
        else
            Errores.turnoyapasado();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.crearLog(e.getMessage().toString());
    }

}

public String getPaciente() {
    return paciente;
}

public void setPaciente(String string) {
    this.paciente = string;
}

public Integer getEstado() {
    return Estado;
}

public void setEstado(Integer estado) {
    this.Estado = estado;
}

    public String getEspecialista() {
        return especialista;
    }

    public void setEspecialista(String especialista) {
        this.especialista = especialista;
    }

}
```

Comment: tu variable de tipo ArrayList `ListaTurnos` como la declaras ?

Comment: @Dev.Joel 
 private List<Turnos> ListaTurnos = null;

Comment: `Turnos tu = (Turnos)ListaTurnos.get(i);` intenta hacer el cast del Objeto

Comment: me devuelve, como mas abajo comente `class [Ljava.lang.Object;`

Comment: obviamente, es un problema de seteo de tipo de objeto, pero, no logro entender como hacerlo que devuelva exactamente el tipo de objeto que quiero

Comment: En el método `ConsultarTurno` , modificar `turnos = turno.list();`   por `turnos =(List<Products>) turno.list();`

Comment: @Dev.Joel ¿Por qué crees que ese código solucionará algo? Los casts explícitos no solucionan errores de runtime, sólo errores de compilación. La clase de la instancia que se está asignando no cambia, así que salta el CCE, sólo que immedatamente antes de la asignación.

Comment: @PabloEzequielFerreyra agrega tu clase PantaListaTurnos.java completa con eso será suficiente para determinar el problema.

Comment: @Elenasys ahi subi toda la clase completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se soluciona indicándole a *hibernate* que debe transformar el resultado de cada fila a la clase que vos desees:

```
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(TuClaseDTO.class))
```

Answer (score 3):

Una pequeña vergüenza del Java: los Generics sólo sirven para comprobaciones en tiempo de compilación, así que si te equivocas en tiempo de ejecución no te servirán de nada.

Tú haces:

```
Query<Turnos> turno = session.createQuery("select t.fechaTurno, t.estados.estado, t.paciente.id from Turnos as t where t.especialista =:especialista");
```

Y piensas que la select te devolverá instancias de `Turno` sólo porque has parametrizado el tipo, o al menos te informará de que hay un error de tipo. Error. Esa información no está en tiempo de ejecución, así que, lo que pasa es:

- El compilador se asegura que el resultado de `list()` debe tratarse como `List<Turno>` (error de compilación si no). Eso está bien.
- El compilador se asegura de que al hacer un `get` sobre esa lista, el resultado debe tratarse como una instancia de `Turno`, correcto.
- Cuando Hibernate devuelve el resultado, lo que devuelve es una **lista de arrays** en vez de una lista de `Turno`, pero en tiempo de ejecución no hay ninguna comprobación (de hecho, ni siquiera existe la información de parametrización); el runtime espera un `List` (a secas) y está feliz porque ha recibido un `List` (a secas).
- Al hacer el get, ya estás asignando un array a una referencia a `Turno`. Eso sí que lo comprueba la JVM y lanza el error.

¿Y porqué devuelve una lista de arrays? Pues porque has hecho un select de 3 propiedades, y no de la entidad propiamente dicha. Así que te devuelve, para cada entidad, un array con esas tres propiedades. Si lo que quieres es recuperar la entidad, sencillamente:

```
Query<Turnos> turno = session.createQuery("select t from Turnos t where t.especialista =:especialista");
```

PD:

1) Usa el estándar de nomenclatura de Java (nombres de variables y métodos usan "camelCase" y empiezan por minúscula, ayuda muchísimo a leer el código (y cuánto más fácil sea de leer, más fácil que alguien -tú mismo incluido- encuentre el error).

2) Suele estar bien marcar en el código que muestras cuál es la línea de donde se lanza la excepción para que la gente que lee tus preguntas no tenga que suponerlo.

Comment: claro, cuando ejecuto asi el query, me devuelve correctamente, pero me devuelve un Null Pointer Exception al querer traer la lista a la pantalla, como si tratara de traer algo que no existe (cosa que me huele a correcto, posiblemente sea mi mapeo precisamente, por que lo hago con tres tablas al mismo tiempo)

Comment: Si el problema que planteaste está resuelto con mi solución, marca mi respuesta como correcta y pasa a estudiar el siguiente problema que te aparece. Como tu comentario parece referirse a código que no es parte de la pregunta original, deberías empezar el proceso desde cero (investigar por tu cuenta, encontrar el punto de fallo, mirar las causas -un NPE sólo puede ser porque estés usando una referencia a un objeto `null`-, y si no sale plantear una nueva pregunta).

Answer (score 1):

El problema :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.historiasclinicas.entidades.Turnos

Se genera en este método:

```
private void llenarLista() {

    ListaTurnos = GestorTurnos.ConsultarTurno(especialista, fechaTurno);
    DefaultListModel<Object> df = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaTurnos.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((Turnos)ListaTurnos.get(i)); //ERROR!!!
        Turnos tu = (Turnos)ListaTurnos.get(i);
        df.addElement(tu.getPaciente()+" "+tu.getEstados());
    }
    List.setModel(df);
}
```

En realidad `ListaTurnos` es una lista de objetos `Turnos` ( `List<Turnos>` ) , así que elimina el casting:

```
 System.out.println(String.valueOf(ListaTurnos.get(i))); 
 Turnos tu = ListaTurnos.get(i);
```

Comment: @PabloEzequielFerreyra realiza esto y me comentas resultados.

Comment: no ha funcionado, es el mismo problema que antes, la linea de impresion de consola simplemente era para ver que tipo de objeto trabajaba, pero igual, me sigue devolviendo lo mismo cuando pasa a la linea siguiente

Comment: @PabloEzequielFerreyra veo que usas hibernate! voy a reformular mi respuesta!.

Comment: dale, no hay problema

Answer (score 0):

solucionado, el problema era el mapeo, por algun motivo me estaba dando problemas hibernate al mapear dos tablas, pero al quitar el mapeo de una de ellas (paciente), me resolvio dos problemas en uno, el traer los datos y el mostrarme el apellido, que por el query editor me devolvia como vacio

Answer (score -1):

Esto parece un error causado por una operación no comprobada o no segura (unchecked or unsafe operation).

Un ejemplo típico de este error es :

```
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        List lista2 = lista;
        lista2.add(Integer.valueOf(12));
        String cadena = lista.get(0);
```

Que provoca la excepción :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

Esto se debe a que hemos añadido un Integer a una lista de String a través de una lista no tipada. Es posible que lo mismo esté ocurriendo en tu programa, aunque a lo largo de operaciones más separadas y por tanto más difícil de distinguir.

La forma de ver si esto es así es comprobar qué tipo devuelve la llamada a `ListaTurnos.get(i)`.

```
private void llenarLista() {
    ListaTurnos = GestorTurnos.ConsultarTurno(especialista, fechaTurno);
    DefaultListModel<Object> df = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaTurnos.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println( ListaTurnos.get(i).getClass().toString(); //Imprime tipo
        Turnos tu = ListaTurnos.get(i);
        df.addElement(tu.getPaciente().getId().toString()+" "+tu.getEstados().getEstado().toString());
    }
    List.setModel(df);
}
```

Si el tipo impreso no es `com.historiasclinicas.entidades.Turnos` es una clara indicación de que el problema va por aquí.

Comment: me devuelve directamente como `class [Ljava.lang.Object;`

Comment: dejo mi repositorio por si lo queres ver, por que la verdad, es la primera vez que me pasa, estoy copiando el codigo de otra pantalla con otras clases, pero que en definitiva es exactamente lo mismo que intento hacer actualmente

https://bitbucket.org/pferreyraok/historiasclinicas